# Org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException

Tags: java, spring

MY test has an error in line 97 I it should be that I don't know how to give to mock the right value to process from my controller

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/remove", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String remove(
            @ModelAttribute( "id" ) String id, Model model
    ) {
        bookService.removeOne(Long.parseLong(id.substring(8)));
        List<Book> bookList = bookService.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("bookList", bookList);

        return "redirect:/book/bookList";
    }
```

The method remove one with id substring 8, how can I represent this in my test.
Specific error is written below

```
@Mock
    BookService bookService;  // will be inject to BookController

    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        new BookController(bookService);
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = standaloneSetup(controller)
                .setSingleView(new InternalResourceView("/book/bookList"))
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void bookRemoveTest() throws Exception {
        securityService.autologin("admin", "admin");
        Book book = new Book();
        book.setId(1L);
        BookService bookService = mock(BookService.class);
        bookService.removeOne( book.getId());
        expect(bookService.findOne(anyLong())).andReturn(book);
        replay(bookService);
        MvcResult result = mockMvc
                .perform(post("/book/remove")
                        .accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                        .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML))

                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(model().attributeExists("bookList"))
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML))
                .andReturn();

    }

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -8

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:65)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:167)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:155)
    at com.admintest.controller.BookControllerTest.bookRemoveTest(BookControllerTest.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at  .evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
```

Comment: I highly doubt that the id is a model attribute. You probably want to pass the id as a request parameter or path parameter.

Comment: yes I want the id to tell the test what book to remove

Comment: As stated pass it as a request parameter of path parameter and change your controller accordingly.

Comment: Please don't use all uppercase, I consider that as rude. You aren't passing anything in your test. Instead of hacking something together I suggest a read of the spring documentation and get an understanding on what you are trying to do.

Comment: sorry for that a mistake will delete now